# How to cast items in a list to Strings in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

So I have a list of items that I created from a file. I am able to read the file and put the items in my list successfully, but I'm having trouble converting/casting those items into Strings.

So for example:

```
(print myList)
```

produces:

```
'(Apple Orange banana pickle)
```

and:

```
(for ([i lst])
        (print i)
    )
```

produces:

```
'Apple'Orange'banana'pickle
```

which aren't strings.

I really just want a list of strings so I can manipulate them later. Racket documentation seems to show only how to take care of chars. How should I go about doing this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'd recommend a beginner's book such as "The Little Schemer" or "How to Design Programs" to get a hang of the way we solve problems in Scheme. Currently, you're writing code in a non-idiomatic way, as if you were using a traditional procedural language.

Comment: Note that `display` is the correct function to use if you want data displayed without encapsulation. Also if you want something like this then using `write` is perhaps better.

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler, more idiomatic way using the built-in [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) procedure together with [`symbol->string`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html?q=symbol-%3Estring#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._symbol-~3estring%29%29), which performs exactly the conversion you need:

```
(map symbol->string '(apple orange banana pickle))
=> '("apple" "orange" "banana" "pickle")
```

Remember that in Scheme, most of the time we avoid mutating operations such as `set!` - Scheme favors a functional style of programming, where we build new data instead of modifying it.

Also notice that we avoid explicit looping - there are built-in procedures for manipulating lists in any way you can imagine, and for those rare cases when we don't find a procedure that meets our needs, we loop using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer. I believe the items I have in my list are called "symbols" in racket. So there is a method "symbol->string" that you can use.

So I defined a new list called "stringList", and did this:

```
;Create new list to be list of strings
(define stringList '())

;convert symbols from list into strings and add to stringList
(for ([i myList])
  (set! i (symbol->string i))
  (set! stringList (cons i stringList))
)
```

Would still love to hear any feedback!

Comment: Notice that elements in the output list appear in reverse order.

Comment: Don’t use `for` to do this, use `for/list` (or `map` as @ÓscarLópez suggests). `set!` is almost never what you want.

Comment: Please don't use `set!` !